# build multiple artifacts from different modules using maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I have a set of modules (A) and a set of artifacts (B). I can build any artifact in B by selecting a combination of modules in A. However, now in Maven, **looks like** I cannot do that. I can have a master pom file that include every module in A (each module now has a pom file), but don't have the luxury of picking any module to throw in a certain artifact. Or am I missing something?

Thanks.